# How to remove dots from outputfile in logstash

Tags: logstash

I am trying to remove dots which are there in the input file from getting copied to output file. Can some one please help me on that

Input file : _ABC ........ null
Expected output : _ABC null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using grok{}, you'd need to escape them in your pattern: "\.".

If you just want to get rid of a series of periods, [mutate->gsub](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-gsub) can do it:

```
filter {
    mutate {
        gsub => [ "message", "\.+", "" ]
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no specific pattern in the input message that will let me choose the field when i use gsub. Is there a way we can search the whole output file for ... and then replace it ?

Comment: The current outputfile looks like this: ABCstatus: _ABCHost ........ null _PQHost ......... null _Port .......... 0 _so ......... null _psOut .......... null _dis . table. ABCSocketThread Cluster............... 1.2.3.4 Server.......... 9.63.246.203 Load............. -1 ConnectionInfoFromUserspace?... false What i expect is ABCSocketThread status: _ABCHost null _PQHost null _Port  0 _so null _psOut null _dis . ABC Cluster1.2.3.4 Server 9.63.246.203 Load -1 . how can we formulate gsub in this case.i am kind of new to logstash. please help